# How to process json inside json to model in flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter

This is the response from client API and i want to process it to insert it inside list

```
[
    {
        "title": "Test",
        "status": "0",
        "transkrip": null,
        "show_item": "1",
        "created_date": "2022-04-28 13:33:55",
        "mic_id": null
    },
    {
        "title": "Test 100",
        "status": "0",
        "transkrip": "[{\"speaker\":{\"ms_speaker_id\":2,\"ms_person_id\":408,\"name_person\":\"Janses Simbolon\",\"mic_id\":null,\"absent\":1},\"start\":\"2021-06-29T11:48:10.003909\",\"end\":\"2021-06-29T11:52:13.804033\",\"text\":\"Test trying speaker test\"},{\"speaker\":{\"ms_speaker_id\":2,\"ms_person_id\":396,\"name_person\":\"Abdul Latif Lubis, M.Pd.\",\"mic_id\":null,\"absent\":1},\"start\":\"2021-06-29T11:52:14.118204\",\"end\":\"2021-06-29T11:52:29.876505\",\"text\":\"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\"}]",
        "show_item": "1",
        "created_date": "2022-04-28 13:35:02",
        "mic_id": null
    }
]
```

Comment: first create model of your object and using loop set data (from api) in model and then add that model in your list

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to this site :

[Json2Dart](https://www.webinovers.com/web-tools/json-to-dart-convertor)

And
[image]

Set a class name Which you want to see in your flutter and finally just copy and paste your json response in Json to be converted place and click covert to dart.

Comment: i am sorry but it says "This structure is not currently supported"

Comment: use this https://app.quicktype.io/ tool

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72416176/13577765 I have mentioned all the steps